# toString Method of StringWriter changes TimeZone

Tags: java, date, timezone, rss, datetime-format

I am writing an RssFeed with Rome RSS and after calling the toString method of the StringWriter it changes the TimeZone.
I want to have a fixed Timezone and Time independent from the machine where the code is running.

Before calling the toString method the date looks like this:

```
Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 CET 2014
```

After calling the toString method it looks like this:

```
Sun, 09 Nov 2014 23:00:00 GMT
```

It also does not change anything when I set the Locale directly before

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "CA"));
String rssFeedString = writer.toString();
```

How can I prevent this behavior?
I have no direct access to use DateFormater because its inside ROME RSS API.

```
SyndFeedOutput output = new SyndFeedOutput();
output.output(feed, writer);
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE"));
String rssFeedString = writer.toString();
writer.close();
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Aside from anything else, you haven't explicitly told us what you're formatting. My *guess* is that it's a java.util.Date, but that's unclear. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Err, no. `StringWriter` accumulates chars in a char array, and its `toString()` method returns those chars as a `String`. It doesn't have anything whatsoever to do with timezones. Your supposition is ludicrous.

Comment: https://github.com/rometools/rome/issues/188 Here is the behavior explained.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with StringWriter itself. What about setting the locale at the application start or using system properties? `-Duser.language=de -Duser.country=DE -Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin`

Comment: On app start it is not possible for some reasons, but I try Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE")); and does not changed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the `toString()` methods as informative for date, time and numbers. You should not rely on the output as it may be locale dependent (you've found that out already).

I suggest you using the DateFormat class to make the date format fixed regarding the system locale

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
// optionally you can set your timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(someDate));
```